# "Insert SparkSession Dataframe" doesn't exist - IBM Watson studio

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, parquet, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I'm following this online course by IBM: [Advanced Machine Learning course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/advanced-machine-learning-signal-processing/home/welcome).

I would like to load a `.csv` file and then store it as a `parquet` format in my Cloud Object Storage inside my Watson Project (here you can find how to access to the storage [Object Storage Watson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=15&v=JutuwlhgDiI&feature=emb_logo)).

The teacher of the course is using the following method: [add files to Object Storage](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-do-you-write-spark-dataframe-parquet-file-format-cloud-object-storage).

Basically the documentation shows how to automatically retrieve the Object Cloud credential and URL using `Insert SparkSession Dataframe` option.

I can't find this option at all, i tried almost everything, but clicking on my imported `.csv` (as suggested in the documentation) only gives me `pandas Dataframe` option.

What am i doing wrong? I followed each step carefully, i tried almost all the possible envirorments available (Free CPU Python 3.6, Apache Spark Python 3.6 ecc...) with no success, the option won't show at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

You need to create a new envirorment and add Spark to it.

Then once you create your notebook, select this envirorment, load a dummy `.json` file and you'll be able to select `Insert SparkSession Dataframe`.